# Let $\{a_n\}$ be a Cauchy Sequence in $M$. Prove that the set $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{a_n\}$  be a Cauchy Sequence in $M$. Prove that the set $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

Proof: let $\{a_n\}$  be a Cauchy sequence in $M$, then there exists a $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $n,m \geq N$ implies $d(a_n,a_m) < \varepsilon$.

Thus, $a_n$ is bounded by $N$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, it is not. Read what your statements say carefully. $N$ has nothing to do with an upper or lower bound of the values of the $a_n$, but is a lower bound on the index $n$.

Comment: The bound has to do with $\varepsilon$, not with $N$.

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:*

For $\epsilon = 1$ there exists an $N$ such that for all $n, m > N$, $|a_n - a_m| < 1$ and in particular $|a_{N+1} - a_m| < 1$ for all $m > N$.

Can you now find an upper and lower bound on all $a_n$?

Answer (score 0):

But is not $\mathbb{R}$, i.ea
Suppose $(\forall \epsilon > 0)(\exists N> 0)(n, m> N \Rightarrow d(x_n,x_m)<\epsilon)$.Prove$ (\exists x\in x) (\epsilon> 0)( \forall n> 1)d(x_n, x)<\epsilon$.
Any hint? For your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Cauchy sequences converge. Thus the tail of such sequences are bounded between (L-epsilon,L+epsilon). But then the whole sequence is bounded because any finite set (the first k terms) is also bounded.